# Is it correct or safe to throw an Exception whose message includes the offending value?

Tags: java, security, validation

Let's say you are writing a generic `doSomething` method where you check a string argument for validity:

```
public void doSomething(String argument) {
   if(!checkArgument(argument)) {
      // Argument is not valid
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument " + argument + " is not valid");
   }

   ...
```

Is throwing an Exception whose message can contain potentially arbitrary text safe? Or can it expose the program to log forging or some other security issues?

Is there any best practice to handle such cases?

Comment: If it could really be anything, you could at least truncate it (in case you've just received a 10 million-character-long string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you are going to do with the exception after it is thrown.
In general, I'd say this is probably a bad idea. As a rule of thumb you should never "use" unsanitized arguments.  Here are a few attack scenarios this might open you up to.

1. This is for a webpage and you are displaying this error to the user. In this case the attacker could execute a [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack, among other things.
2. This error will be printed to a log. Here it may seem safe, but the attacker still has some (all be it limited) access to your file system. They could use this mechanism to store code for future use, or possibly damage the log (or other aspects of the file system). This is especially true if argument is written byte for byte to a file.
3. This error will be stored in a database. Here with enough schema information the attacker may be able to alter, or destroy the entirety of the database.

On it's own this might not be enough for an attacker to steal any information, but combined with other bugs this could be used to gain control of the machine. You could do some basic sanitization though and avoid most of these issues.

1. As suggested by @assylias perform length checking.
2. Ensure all characters in argument are alphanumeric (or whatever you expect things in arg to be).
3. If alphanumeric is to restrictive, pass through any whitelist that doesn't include html/javascript/sql syntax characters (e.g. '<','>',';') Usually these characters do not need to be present for debugging anyways.

Comment: You should sanitize the value when output for the context of the output. e.g. if you have an HTML custom error page that shows the exception message then it should output the entire message HTML encoded. It should not be up to the class the exception is created in (or the exception class itself) to ensure encoding as it has no idea of the context where it will be output.

Comment: I think that's the wrong way to think about it. If you have injection vulnerabilities fix those (in such a way that they can never come back).

Comment: @silverlightfox You are absolutely correct. My main point was it depends how you use the exception. I agree any sanitization should happen then, and not when the exception is thrown. I stand by my point though, that this is generally a bad idea. It is much easier/safer to not include the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Generally safe, but you should decide whether to allow exceptions to be visible to end users if the code is executing on a system under your control (e.g. a web server). Showing internal information in error messages in exceptions is a form of [Information Leakage](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Information_Leakage) as it can reveal information about how your system is built and an attacker can probe for vulnerabilities by forcing exceptions. This may not apply if it is a desktop application, as this is effectively under user control anyway, but extra caution is needed to anything web or internet based.

However, you could add logic to your custom error handler page to only show the details of exceptions that derive from  `MyUserExceptionClass` which you make it your policy to only use when the end user can rectify the error. In this case you'll probably only want to show the message itself and not output any stack trace or other details, in which case your exception message *should* contain details of the argument name if it is relevant to the end user.

To address the points in diedthreetimes's answer, these should not be of concern to the exception throwing class or the exception class itself. The class that uses the unsanitised data should sanitise it for the context it is output.

e.g.

1. If output in an HTML page, HTML encode the exception message at point of output, not at point of exception throwing.
2. The error logging class should sanitise the unsanitised text into the correct format for the log. If there is a character limit or if it is a CSV formatted file then this class should ensure that any commas and quote characters in the message are formatted properly at this point.
3. If written to the database, it is up to the Data Access Layer to correctly write the information into the database using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1):

I broadly agree with SilverlightFox's answer. Worry about injection vulnerabilities at the point they occur (and make sure they cannot occur).

However, confidentiality issues are a real problem with exceptions. Elsewhere (unless we have globals) we are dealing with interactions over a single layer-interface. Bring in exceptions and we have non-local issues.

For example:

- SSNs are the canonical example of data that needs tight controls. Some low-level parsing library may throw an exception with details of the string. That may be caught and shoved into a log. Neither generic parsing code nor logging code know about SSNs but they've ended up introducing an SSN vulnerability.
- Web sites that put exception messages into web pages (sometimes in comments - that doesn't help!) disclose information about the web site implementation that may be helpful to an adversary. Web sites should not do this, but they do. Therefore, you need to think carefully about any code that throws exception and could end up in a web app some day.
- Exceptions propagated between processes, or machines, or operating system to pross, or whatever, may carry confidential information.
- Where there is mobile code, confidential information may be slip down to less privileged code. File paths are the obvious candidate here.

It's also worth noting that adding mutable data to exceptions is a bad idea, as it needs a deep copy to be safe. It's a shame that 1.4 made `Throwable` itself "usefully" mutable.

Answer (score 0):

You can log the argument and include a substring in exception.

For your concern on security it depends on access control model of your application and infrastructure.

1. If server is not accessible to all, then logging is a good idea at least you can have a look at what argument caused exception.
2. If security is a higher concern, I would suggest storing exception details in a database table along with parameter for analysis.
3. If you want to go crazy you can encrypt your database column.

In any case I think one would like to have a look at what argument caused exception.

Cheers !!